# Where to put local-exec command to run before terraform destroy

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform script that creates an aws security group, a few servers, and some dns records. The servers are RHEL 7, and I register them to the Red Hat network. Before I destroy my resources, I would like to automatically unregister these servers, because if I don't, the next time I would like to register them it will fail because all subscriptions are used.

So I made an ansible role that does this for me, and I put

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
  when    = "destroy"
  command = "ansible-playbook playbooks/unregister_rhsm.yml"
}
```

into one of the `resource`s in hope that this would do the trick. It somehow did, however not all servers got deregistered. Which lets me to think that I did not choose the correct place.

How do I know where to put the `provisioner` so that the ansible playbook will run reliably before all destroy action takes place? Or is there a better mechanism to achieve the automatic unregister before destroy? (besides creating a shell script that calls ansible before terraform and using that script instead of `terraform destroy`)

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally put a destroy `provisioner` within each Red Hat `aws_instance` resource such that when it runs it only unregisters that server, rather than one script that tries to unregister all servers. That way, if/when Terraform decides it needs to recreate one server, it won't remove all of your servers from the Red Hat network.

Apart from that, I can't see a problem with what you're doing, you might need to debug the script to see why it's not working.

Comment: Good point. Is there a way to pass an argument to local-exec command so that it knows on which server to act? Ideally the public IP.

Comment: The documentation (https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/connection.html) shows you how to provide a `connection` block either for the whole resource or for a specific `provisioner`.